# Failure to start ufw after OpenVPN connection

Tags: vpn, openvpn, ufw

I have currently configured my Ubuntu system to connect to an OpenVPN server on startup. This is done by placing a configuration file in the `/etc/openvpn` directory.

Additionally, I would like to enable a firewall to ensure all connections go through the VPN. To this end, I have added this line to my OpenVPN configuration:

```
route-up /etc/openvpn/firewall-enable
```

Which points to a bash script with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
ufw enable
```

However, upon a system reboot, the VPN connection is made successfully, but `ufw status` reports that the firewall is still inactive.

*Edit:* stderr output from `ufw enable` command: https://pastebin.com/UYdh6iHq.

Comment: First, what is the contents of your script ? If all it has is `ufw enable` why not call ufw enable directly ? And if ufw is not running the error message is ... (fill in the blank here). Finally, what other commands are you running ?

Comment: Looking at that error message, two possibilities. 1. Is this a virtual machine ? If so, what virtualization technology ? 2. You edited your iptables rules on a windows machine ? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/551718/iptables-unable-to-initialize-table-filter

Comment: See also - https://askubuntu.com/questions/28215/how-can-i-fix-the-iptables-error-message-unable-to-initialize-table-filter . What kernel modules are loaded ?